# Python opencv videowriter issue: not compressing/writing

Tags: python, opencv, encoding

I am currently using opencv in python to write a video with compression. Here are some parts of the code that are giving errors.

```
fourcc=cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'X264')
video = cv2.VideoWriter(outfiles[c],fourcc, fps, (width,height))
```

The error is

OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x34363258/'X264' is not supported with codec id 28 and form
at 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x00000021/'!???'
Working on file test_videos/solidYellowLeft.mp4
OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x34363258/'X264' is not supported with codec id 28 and form
at 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x00000021/'!???'

I have downloaded the openh264-1.6.0-win64msvc.dll file for the newer versions of H264 encoding. I've tried different types, H264, X264, XVID, VIDX, not using MJPG because it produces a large file. Setting the 5th option in VideoWriter to False (making it single channel) didn't work either. If you have a suggestion on how to fix this or to try an alternative method, that would help greatly.. If you need any more information, let me know.

Comment: Just downloading the h264 implementation library won't solve your problem. The `cv2.VideoWriter` uses the FFMPEG API for video encoding, so your copy of FFMPEG must be built with libx264 support.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone came across this error, I solved it by using the fallback tag which removed the error.

```
fourcc=0x00000021
```

Comment: I used this solution on Ubuntu 16.04, and it worked great.  But I have an Ubuntu 18 machine, and now I'm back to the same error.   Anyone have this problem when they upgraded?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `outfiles[c]` contains a filename like `"out.mp4"` the following worked for me on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine with an NVidia GPU.

```py
fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v")
video = cv2.VideoWriter(outfiles[c],fourcc, fps, (width,height))
```

Cheers to jspiers for answering [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1029451/jetson-tx2/-python-what-is-the-four-characters-fourcc-code-for-mp4-encoding-on-tx2/post/5298634/#5298634).